# If $p(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$ find the remainder when $p(x^{12})$ is divided by $p(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> **Question:**
>
> If $p(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$ find the remainder when $p(x^{12})$ is divided by $p(x)$
>
> **Options:**
>
> (A) $0$
>
> (B) $6$
>
> (C) $1+x$
>
> (D) $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$

**My attempt:**

Since $p(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$ is a geometric series assuming $x<1$ with sum
$$S_1=\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}$$
and $p\left(x^{12}\right)$ also is a geometric series with sum
$$S_2=\frac{1-\left(x^{12}\right)^6}{1-x}$$
then
$$\frac{S_2}{S_1}= \frac{1-\left(x^{12}\right)^6}{1-x^6}$$

Now I can't seem to find a way to proceed further.
EDIT
I just found a mistake I made.
$$S_2=\frac{1-\left(x^{12}\right)^6}{1-x^{12}}$$
And not
$$S_2=\frac{1-\left(x^{12}\right)^6}{1-x}$$
So my division was wrong and so was my solution thereafter.
Sorry !

Comment: This is not a geometric series, but a polynomial.

Comment: That's true but I used the geometric series formula to find it's sum.

Comment: Yes you did, but the question is: can you use since this is not a geometric series?

Comment: I couldn't find any other way to simplify it.so i tried using the geometric series formula.its possible that it is a bad approach but I couldn't find a better way.

Comment: Shash, you used the correct formula for a truncated geometric series, so I'm not sure what @Integral is going on about. That was a good approach that nearly finished the problem, as you can see in the answer by lhf. See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html

Comment: @StellaBiderman What I am going about: **1)** You shouldn't call a polynomial a series. **2)** The formula is valid for any $x \neq 1$ not just $x < 1$. He (she) wrote this because he (she) thought in the series $1+x+x^2+\ldots$ and the fact that there is a valid formula when $|x| < 1$. Again, this is an evidence that he (she) is really thinking in series. 

Ignoring this little mistakes can brings bad misconceptions and bad habits.

Comment: @Integral Its a lot easier to use "they" tbh. Anyways, yes it is a series. Yes it is a geometric series. It happens to be a finite geometric series rather than the more common infinite geometric series, which means that the formula works for all $x\neq 1$ instead of all $|x|<1$. I think your approach to deny that it is a series instead of saying that it is a finite series is bad pedagogy.

Comment: @StellaBiderman So you think it makes more sense to abandon the word *sum* and use only *finite series* ? I'm sorry, but this is bad pedagogy.

Answer (score 8):

*Hint:* $\dfrac{S2}{S1}= \dfrac{1-(x^{12})^6}{1-x^6}= \dfrac{1-(x^6)^{12}}{1-x^6}= \dfrac{1-y^{12}}{1-y}$, for $y=x^6$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
\begin{align}
p(x^{12})-6 & = \big(x^{12}-1\big)+\big((x^{12})^2-1\big)+\big((x^{12})^3-1\big)+\big((x^{12})^4-1\big)+\big((x^{12})^5-1\big) \\
 & = (x^{12}-1)( \cdots ) = (x^6-1)(x^6+1)(\cdots) = p(x)\cdot(x-1)(x^6+1)(\cdots)
\end{align}
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ]  The above can also be derived directly from the more general:

$$a(x) - b(x) \mid p\big(a(x)\big) - p\big(b(x)\big) \implies x^{12} - 1 \mid p(x^{12})-p(1) \implies p(x) \mid p(x^{12}) - 6$$